# How to custom placeholder in international phone number plugin

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have problem with custom placeholder. I am using this https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number I want to add more ex. E.g. 131123456789 to my place holder which default gave something like this 131123456789. I read the document they use customPlaceholder to custom place holder, but they do not have any example with angularjs, so could someone show me example code with custom place holder like this.

Here my code that I added to my app

```
app.config([
   '$stateProvider',
   ipnConfig,
   register_form_state
 ])->ipnConfig.customPlaceholder = 'E.g. 131123456789'
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve this problem

http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/

Please refer this link & this is angularJS plugin

https://github.com/hodgepodgers/ng-intl-tel-input

On selection of country, placeholder will change

Comment: Currently, It show like this in my project, but I not want to use default placeholder which is show 131123456789, I want to custom place holder to add E.g more( E.g 131123456789), but I do not know how to custom it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for http://hodgepodgers.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/ is lacking, but it seems like it could be a good tool. I think I would personally like to see a working implementation inside of an existing application before I'd rule it as the solution to use. I'm still having trouble implementing this one compared to the one by mareczek.

*edit* To answer your question, I think that it changes the placeholder based on the flag you have selected. If you have it set to a default country, can you not just change the placeholder in the html? Or can you target it directly using css?